# Launcher icon Xamarin Android not found

Tags: android, xamarin, icons, launcher

I'm doing a Hello World in Xamarin Android, but when I try to change the launcher icon, it throws the following error: "*No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').*"

Actually I don't have any "icon" in my resources, the icons' names are ic_launcher:

[image: Resources structure]

And my manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="HelloWorldXamarinAndroid.HelloWorldXamarinAndroid" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application android:label="Hi android" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></application>
</manifest>
```

I've already cleaned the project and tried to rebuild it, can someone help me?

If I change all the images' names to "Icon.png" and the manifest with "@drawable/Icon", it works, my question is, why Xamarin doesn't work with other names

I found the problem, in Main Activity is set the icon too, so it's necessary to set the new name there too:

```
[Activity(Label = "HelloWorldXamarinAndroid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: The manifest is auto-generated in part from Xamarin provided C# Attributes during build. It should only be manually modified in the most extreme of cases, when all else has failed.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the **Droid** project and select **Android Manifest** from the menu list. Under **Application Icon** you will see which icon the application is referencing.

Below is a picture of where the icon is being references.

[image]

Comment: In the solution Drawable folders there are .png files and a .xml files with the same name. Which is the purpose of the .xml? The icon you are referencing is the .png or the .xml? I think it is the .xml but I crash the app everytime I try to change its code to replace the .png

Comment: You're setting the PNG to use as the application icon in the above example. The XML files are fully described in this Xamarin thread. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/155994/icons-in-android-mipmap-folders